# Using delayed job I want to modify reschedule_at based on error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Using the error, failure and reschedule_at callbacks is there a way to make reschedule_at time depend on what type of error i receive?

I have set the reschedule_at method but if affects all jobs of this type. I don't know where to handle this behavior based on error type and in what handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some testing it seems that you can do custom rescheduling based on the particular job error message with the following approach:

1. Define an instance variable in the job to hold the custom retry delay. This variable **will get serialized to the database** (or any other DelayedJob backend) among all other variables, i.e. its state will be preserved between job runs.
2. In the `error` hook, set the delay to any value **based on the error that you'll get in the `exception` parameter** (which is an `Exception` object).
3. Use that custom delay in the `reschedule_at` method.

The solution leverages the fact that the `reschedule_at` method [is called **after** the `error` hook](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/401f43e076c25559ec65fdfa611a0d94b7b29eb1/lib/delayed/worker.rb#L234). See the following example:

```
class MyJob

  attr_accessor :retry_delay

  def initialize
    self.retry_delay = 5 # default retry delay
  end

  def error(job, exception)
    # set up a different the delay time on a specific error
    if exception.is_a? NameError
      self.retry_delay = 10
    end
  end

  def reschedule_at(current_time, attempts)
    current_time + retry_delay.seconds
  end

end
```